# AffinityKeyMapped not working with Ignite 2.4/2.5/2.6 and Scala

Tags: scala, ignite

Using Scala 2.11.7/Java 1.8.0_161/RHEL7.

We have two caches whose elements share the same affinity key. The affinity key is defined as follows:

```
case class IgniteTradePayloadKey(
    @(AffinityKeyMapped@field)
    tradeKey: TradeKey,
    ... other fields
) extends Serializable

case class IgniteDealPayloadKey(
   @(AffinityKeyMapped@field)
   tradeKey: TradeKey,
   child: Int,
   ... other fields
) extends Serializable
```

Those are used as key to two ignite caches (Trades and Deals). We want instances of Trades and Deals to be collocated, as we perform computations using both. Think of them as having a parent/child relationship, and we would like to keep the parent and its children in the same node because our calculations require both. Parents are uniquely identified by TradeKey, so we use that in both caches to control affinity. Note that they are also used as part of the Ignite key itself. They are not part of the value.

This worked beautifully with Ignite 1.7; we then tried to upgrade to a more recent version of Ignite (we tried 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6), and without any code change whatsoever, there are children that are no longer collocated with their parents. Reverted back to 1.7 to be sure, and collocation works. We tried to override the affinity function with something simple (just a hash on the TradeKey), and again, it works with 1.7, but not with any of the 2.X versions listed above.

What are we missing?

Configuration as requested (apologies for the massive file). We tried with and without defining our own affinity function, with the same results.

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
              class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK"/>
            <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="CLIENT_MODE" class="java.lang.String">
            <constructor-arg value="${IGNITE_CLIENT_MODE:false}" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Ignite common configuration -->
        <bean abstract="true" id="common.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <property name="gridName" value="MTS Trades Cache Grid" />
            <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
            <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
            <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="clientMode" ref="CLIENT_MODE"/>
            <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="4"/>
            <property name="deploymentMode" value="CONTINUOUS"/>

            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="localPort" value="47700"/>
                    <property name="localPortRange" value="20"/>

                    <!-- Setting up IP finder for this cluster -->
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                            <property name="addresses">
                                <list>
                                    <value>127.0.0.1:47700..47720</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="communicationSpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                    <property name="localPort" value="49100"/>
                    <property name="sharedMemoryPort" value="-1" />
                    <property name="messageQueueLimit" value="1024"/>

                </bean>
            </property>

            <!-- Cache configuration -->
            <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                <list>
                    <!-- deals -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="dealPayloads" />
                        <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
                        <property name="backups" value="0" />
                        <property name="OnheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/>

                        <property name="queryEntities">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                    <!-- setting indexed type's key class -->
                                    <property name="keyType" value="com.company.ignite.IgniteDealPayloadKey" />
                                    <!-- setting indexed type's value class -->
                                    <property name="valueType" value="com.company.ignite.IgniteDealPayload" />
                                </bean>
                            </list>
                        </property>

                        <property name="affinity">
                            <bean class="com.company.ignite.affinity.IgniteAffinityFunction">
                                <property name="partitions" value="1024"/>
                            </bean>
                        </property>

                        <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
                        <property name="rebalanceMode" value="ASYNC" />
                        <property name="copyOnRead" value="false" />

                        <!-- Set rebalance batch size to 8 MB. -->
                        <property name="rebalanceBatchSize" value="#{8 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

                        <!-- Explicitly disable rebalance throttling. -->
                        <property name="rebalanceThrottle" value="0"/>

                        <!-- Set 4 threads for rebalancing. -->
                        <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="4"/>

                    </bean>
                    <!-- trade versions -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="tradePayloads" />
                        <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
                        <property name="backups" value="0" />
                        <property name="OnheapCacheEnabled" value="true"/>

                        <property name="queryEntities">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                    <!-- setting indexed type's key class -->
                                    <property name="keyType" value="com.company.ignite.IgniteTradePayloadKey" />
                                    <!-- setting indexed type's value class -->
                                    <property name="valueType" value="com.company.ignite.IgniteTradePayload" />
                                </bean>
                            </list>
                        </property>

                        <property name="affinity">
                            <bean class="com.company.ignite.affinity.IgniteAffinityFunction">
                                <property name="partitions" value="1024"/>
                            </bean>
                        </property>

                        <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
                        <property name="rebalanceMode" value="ASYNC" />
                        <property name="copyOnRead" value="false" />

                        <!-- Set rebalance batch size to 8 MB. -->
                        <property name="rebalanceBatchSize" value="#{8 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

                        <!-- Explicitly disable rebalance throttling. -->
                        <property name="rebalanceThrottle" value="0"/>

                        <!-- Set 4 threads for rebalancing. -->
                        <property name="rebalanceThreadPoolSize" value="4"/>

                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

In addition, this is the relevant exception:

```
    [22:28:24,418][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#23%MTS Trades Cache Grid%][IgniteKernal%MTS Trades Cache Grid] FreeList [name=MTS Trades Cache Grid, buckets=256, dataPages=9658, reusePages=0]
    [22:28:57,335][INFO][pub-#314%MTS Trades Cache Grid%][GridDeploymentLocalStore] Class locally deployed: class com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob
    [22:28:57,705][SEVERE][pub-#314%MTS Trades Cache Grid%][GridJobWorker] Failed to execute job [jobId=48df049c461-b3ba568d-6a39-4296-b03f-0c046e7cf3f7, ses=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob, dep=GridDeployment [ts=1532382444003, depMode=CONTINUOUS, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6, clsLdrId=a717c19c461-e5241c47-40d4-4085-a7fa-4f1916275b2e, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionFullMap, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=2], taskClsName=com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob, sesId=38df049c461-b3ba568d-6a39-4296-b03f-0c046e7cf3f7, startTime=1532384937062, endTime=1532388537300, taskNodeId=b3ba568d-6a39-4296-b03f-0c046e7cf3f7, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, internal=false, topPred=null, subjId=b3ba568d-6a39-4296-b03f-0c046e7cf3f7, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT, res=null, hash=1635946755]], execName=null], jobId=48df049c461-b3ba568d-6a39-4296-b03f-0c046e7cf3f7]]
    class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: null
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1858)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:566)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6623)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:560)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:489)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1189)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1921)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1555)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1183)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1090)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ComputeJob.scala:49)
            at com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(ComputeJob.scala:47)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
            at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:79)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
            at scala.collection.AbstractSet.scala$collection$SetLike$$super$map(Set.scala:47)
            at scala.collection.SetLike$class.map(SetLike.scala:92)
            at scala.collection.AbstractSet.map(Set.scala:47)
            at com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob$$anonfun$1.apply(ComputeJob.scala:47)
            at com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob$$anonfun$1.apply(ComputeJob.scala:44)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:221)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:428)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:428)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
            at com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob.call(ComputeJob.scala:44)
            at com.company.pt.tradesrouter.routing.ComputeJob.call(ComputeJob.scala:21)
            at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1855)
            ... 14 more
```

Comment: Do you mean that two objects in different caches with the same `tradeKey` are stored on different nodes? That shouldn't be possible. Please show your cache configs and the code that you use to understand that the objects are not collocated.

Comment: The code is complex, as it involves calculations. The call is:

`val nodeMappings = ignite.affinity(IgniteInterface.IGNITE_TRADE_PAYLOADS_CACHE_NAME).mapKeysToNodes(igniteTradeKeys)`

Long story short, we have a bunch of keys, we partition them based on the call above, and then we send an async compute call to those nodes. We expect that trades and deals with the same keys are collocated, so for a given key, a localPeek on deals should never return  null - but it does on occasion. Code works fine with 1.7 but fails with 2.4 on the same data set.

Comment: You can remove your calculations from the code and leave only the parts that matter for the problem (e.g. code like `assert localPeek(key) != null` instead of all the calculations). If you provide a runnable reproducer (e.g. as a couple of files shared on GitHub) that community can review, run and debug, you'll surely get an answer much faster.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that `mapKeysToNodes` returns a correct mapping with the keys being collocated, but `localPeek` isn't returning the entries? In other words, `mapKeysToNodes` says that a key `K` is stored on a node `N`, but then you send a job to `N` that does `localPeek(K)` and you get `null`. Is that what's happening?

Comment: Please share your Ignite configuration.

Comment: Configuration above. And your understanding is correct - `mapKeysToNodes` says that `K` is stored on `N`, but when we call `localPeek(K)` on that node, we get a null back.

Could this be related to the version of Scala we are running (2.11)?

Comment: Scala version - not really, unless scalac does something weird to your classes. Configuration also seems fine. Is there a chance that the keys are not yet put into the caches by the time you execute a `localPeek`? `mapKeysToNodes` doesn't require a key to actually be present in the cluster, it just says where it would be based on the affinity mappings.

Comment: Also, check out the logs and share them if possible (github/gist link would be OK). Note that Ignite runs in quite mode by default, so `stdout` doesn't contain all the logs - you need to look for the log files in the work directory.

Comment: The data is static in our test, we load it first (both caches) and then run the test. We will get to the logs shortly.

Comment: I added the relevant log to the original post. The line on our side causing grief is:

`key.child -> ByteBuffer.wrap(dealPayloadsCache.localPeek(key).payload)`

The localPeek is returning null.

Comment: To debug this, I'd suggest to, e.g., replace the compute job with `localPeek` with a regular `get` to see if the key is accessible at all. Also, make sure the compute closure isn't capturing any Ignite components. E.g. `compute.run(() -> cache.localPeek(k))` isn't correct as you're sending the `cache` over the network. Correct code would be something like `compute.run(() -> Igntition.localIgnite().cache("mycache").localPeek(k))`.

Comment: OK, this is really weird. I printed the note to key associations we get from mapKeysToNodes for both caches and then compared the node ids for each one of the keys. They are all mapped to the same nodes. Then inside my compute job, I call local peek for both caches; for Trades, localPeek always returns something. For Deals, it always returns null. A call to get for deals always returns something, which means the deal data is actually stored on another node.

Comment: What I don't understand is how this can be possible since calling mapKeysToNodes OUTSIDE the Ignite nodes returns the correct mapping, but when calling localPeek the information is somewhere else. Again, bear in mind that this exact same code works fine with 1.7.

Comment: Have you tried `get` instead of `localPeek`? `mapKeysToNodes` doesn't check if a key actually exists, it just says where it *would've been*. If `mapKeysToNodes` says that a key `K` is on a node `N`, but `localPeek` on `N` returns `null` then the most logical answer is that `K` is not stored in the cluster at all.

Comment: Also, just to check, you're calling `mapKeysToNodes` two times on two different `Affinity` objects for two caches, right? And you're comparing the results and they are the same for both caches (which they should be because of the affinity key)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you hit a bug, that was introduced in Ignite 2.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5795

Because of this bug `@AffinityKeyMapped` annotation is ignored in classes, that are used in query entity configuration. As far as I can see, this is exactly your case.

It's going to be fixed in Ignite 2.7.

There is a workaround for this problem: you can list the problematic classes in [BinaryConfiguration#classNames](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/BinaryConfiguration.html#setClassNames-java.util.Collection-) configuration property. Binary configuration should be specified as [IgniteConfiguration#binaryConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setBinaryConfiguration-org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration-). This configuration should be the same on all nodes. You may also need to configure [CacheConfiguration#keyConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setKeyConfiguration-org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheKeyConfiguration...-) for your cache.

Comment: **BINGO!!!!** Unfortunately I can only upvote once. If you ever come to Houston, let me know, I owe you a lot of beers.