# Getting old data after call put

Tags: ignite

I put an Object into cache using 'put' method on a client node; then I get it on other client node, do some logic and put an new Object with same Key as before. I think the new Object will recover the old one because of using same key, but in fact I get the old one after few minutes.It is strange that I get the new one after more few minutes. I have three server nodes and cacheWriteSynchronizationMode is "FULL_SYNC".

sample:

```
// The problem code. 
// The mothed means getting the Object from cache by key and using only once. 
// In fact, I still get the old one by using this method after few minutes, and get right one after more few minutes.
private MyEntity getAndClear(long entityId) {   
    MyEntity pocketLineEntity = dao.selectByEntityId(entityId);// get Object may used by other place from cache
    if(pocketLineEntity == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // I want to use only once, so clear the content of Object here. My method is inserting a new empty Object into cache with same key.
    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
    entity.setEntityId(entityId);
    dao.insert(entity);// insert new Object

    // return old one getted before
    return pocketLineEntity; // do some thing in other code, and only use once, because I insert new one
}




// Here is the code of dao
// select method
public MyEntity selectByEntityId(long entityId) {
    MyEntityKey key = new MyEntityKey();
    key.setEntityId(entityId);
    MyEntity entity = cache.get(key);// ignite cache (IgniteCache<MyEntityKey, MyEntity>)
    return entity;

}

// insert method
public void insert(MyEntity entity) {
    MyEntityKey key = new MyEntityKey();
    key.setEntityId(entity.getEntityId());
    cache.put(key, entity);// ignite cache (IgniteCache<MyEntityKey, MyEntity>)
}






// The class of MyEntityKey 
public class MyEntityKey {
    private long entityId;

    public MyEntityKey() {
    }

    public MyEntityKey(long entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        MyEntityKey key = (MyEntityKey) o;
        return entityId == key.entityId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (entityId ^ (entityId >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    public long getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(long entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }
}
```

part of cache config:

```
    private void init(Ignite ignite) {
    // cache config
    CacheConfiguration<MyEnityKey, MyEnity> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
    cfg.setName(MyEnity.class.getSimpleName().toUpperCase());
    cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    cfg.setBackups(1);
    cfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
    cfg.setCopyOnRead(true);
    cfg.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);
    cfg.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC);
    cfg.setPartitionLossPolicy(PartitionLossPolicy.IGNORE);
    cfg.setQueryEntities(Arrays.asList(createQueryEntity()));
    cfg.setSqlIndexMaxInlineSize(30);
    CacheKeyConfiguration cacheKeyConfiguration = new CacheKeyConfiguration(MyEnityKey.class);
    cacheKeyConfiguration.setAffinityKeyFieldName("entityId");
    cfg.setKeyConfiguration(cacheKeyConfiguration);

    // lru
    cfg.setDataRegionName(MyEnity.class.getSimpleName());
    LruEvictionPolicy evictionPolicy = new LruEvictionPolicy(3600000);
    cfg.setEvictionPolicy(evictionPolicy);



    // read through
    cfg.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(MyEnityMongoStore.class));
    cfg.setCacheStoreSessionListenerFactories(daoConfig.getCacheStoreSessionListenerFactories());

    cfg.setReadThrough(true);
    cfg.setWriteThrough(true);
    cfg.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);
    cfg.setWriteBehindFlushThreadCount(1);
    cfg.setWriteBehindFlushSize(10240);
    cfg.setWriteBehindFlushFrequency(300000);
    cfg.setWriteBehindBatchSize(512);
    IgniteCache<MyEnityKey, MyEnity> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);  

}

private QueryEntity createQueryEntity() {
    QueryEntity queryEntity = new QueryEntity();

    // key-value
    queryEntity.setKeyType(MyEnityKey.class.getName());
    queryEntity.setValueType(MyEnity.class.getName());

    // fields
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    fields.put("entityId", long.class.getName());
    fields.put("pocketLines", String.class.getName());
    queryEntity.setFields(fields);

    return queryEntity;
}
```

Comment: Could you share a code sample that reproduces this issue? What are the key and value types? What does the code that performs the writing look like?

Comment: @Denis Thank you for your reply. I have share the problem code. The problem does not always appear. It never appears in development 's environment, and only appears in production's environment sometimes.

Comment: The hash code implementation seems to be incorrect. I would remove equals and hashCode methods from the key class, since Ignite doesn't use them anyway. Did you configure a custom identity resolver or something like that? Could you also share your cache configuration?

Comment: @Denis Thanks again for your reply.I had shared part of the cache config. I can't make sure equals and hashCode methods making the problem happended, because the problem appeared only few times online. and I can't make it appeared  locally.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to the following bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5795

A fix for it is planned for inclusion into Ignite 2.8

Currently you can solve it by specifying [BinaryConfiguration#classNames](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/BinaryConfiguration.html#setClassNames-java.util.Collection-) on all nodes. Refer to the following question: [AffinityKeyMapped not working with Ignite 2.4/2.5/2.6 and Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451243/affinitykeymapped-not-working-with-ignite-2-4-2-5-2-6-and-scala/51628339#51628339)

Comment: Thank you very much! I 'll try it later.